# Regex to validate string having only characters (not special characters), blank spaces and numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to validate a string that can have only characters (not special characters - case insensitive), blank spaces and numbers.

In my validation code I have:

```
validates :name,
  :presence   => true,
  :format     => { :with => regex } # Here I should set the 'regex'
```

How I should state the regex?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this. If you only want to allow ASCII word characters (no accented characters like Ê or letters from other alphabets like Ӕ or ל), use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$/
```

If you want to allow only numbers and letters from other languages for **Ruby 1.8.7**, use this:

```
/^(?:[^\W_]|\s)*$/u
```

If you want to allow only numbers and letters from other languages for **Ruby 1.9.x**, use this:

```
^[\p{Word}\w\s-]*$
```

Also, if you are planning to use 1.9.x regex with unicode support in Ruby on Rails, add this line at the beginning of your .rb file:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Comment: @ream88 - Thank you; edited to remove `\p{L}` version. It was sloppy of me not to check with such a short regex. The `\p{L}` doesn't work--why? Is it not supported in Ruby regex? It works fine in .NET.

Comment: @Justin Morgan - And what about validating accented characters like à, è, é, ò, ... in the string?

Comment: @Backo - If you use [the `u` flag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm), it should match those. [Tested here](http://rubular.com/r/EMofPxqMXU).

Comment: @Volte - Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @Volte - That's not really relevant to this question. We don't know anything about what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for:

`[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+`

The `+` says one or more so it'll not match empty string. If you need to match them as well, use `*` in place of `+`.

Comment: @eugen - That will allow `_`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what have been said, assign any of the regular expresion to your regex variable in your control this, for instance

```
regex = ^[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$
```