# Regex to validate strings having only characters (without special characters but with accented characters), blank spaces and numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to validate a string that can contain only characters (case insensitive characters), blank spaces and numbers.

More:

- special characters *are not* allowed (eg: !"£$%&/()=?^) except `-` and `_`;
- accented characters *are* allowed (eg: à, è, é, ò, ...);

The regex that I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765020/regex-to-validate-string-having-only-characters-not-special-characters-blank-s) is `^[a-zA-Z\d\s]*$` but this do not validate special characters and accented characters.

**So, how I should improve the regex?**

Comment: When you say "characters", do you mean "letters"? All strings contain characters. A, 7, %, and ▲ are all characters.

Comment: Provided regex doesn't allow special characters `!"£$%&/()=?^`...

Comment: @Justin Morgan - Yes, I mean "letters". Apologize for my vagueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the [`^(?:[^\W_]|\s)*$` answer in the question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765020/regex-to-validate-string-having-only-characters-not-special-characters-blank-s/6765261#6765261) (which actually would have been different if I'd known you wanted to allow _ and -). Not being a Ruby guy myself, I didn't realize that Ruby defaults to not using Unicode for regex matching.

Sorry for my lack of Ruby experience. [What you want to do is use the `u` flag.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) That switches to Unicode (UTF-8), so accented characters are caught. **Here's the pattern you want:**

```
^[\w\s-]*$
```

[And here it is in action at Rubular.](http://rubular.com/r/E2Ih3k1Fzo) This should do the trick, I think.

The `u` flag [works on my original answer as well,](http://rubular.com/r/oAwgEKeXGR) though that one isn't meant to allow _ or - characters.

Comment: Your regex '^[\w\s-]*$' match also !, ", ', ... that I would like to not match.

Comment: @Backo - [Nope, according to this test, those characters don't match](http://rubular.com/r/avVuPzggl2). `\w` only matches letters, numbers, and `_`. `\s` matches whitespace, and `-` is a literal hyphen when used at the very end of a character class.

Comment: @Backo - That's odd...Rubular uses the Ruby regex engine, so I would expect whatever works on Rubular to work for you. What version of Ruby are you using? I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but the only thing I can think of is that you might not be applying the `u` flag properly. Are you using `/^[\w\s-]*$/u` as your regex syntax?

Comment: @JustinMorgan I think that your solution doesn't work with ruby 1.9.2 I opted for adding the special characters directly into my regex. For example /^[a-zA-Z\sáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚüÜñÑ]*$/i

Answer (score 0):

Something like `^[\w\s\-]*$` should validate characters, blank spaces, minus, and underscore.

Comment: Accented characters are in Ruby not part of `\w` according to [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Comment: I checked the regex on http://rubular.com/ - it seems to work, \w matches accented chars as well.

Answer (score 0):

Validation string only for not allowed characters. In this case |,<,>," and &.

`^[^|<>\"&]*$`