# How to validate text isn't blank in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, chars

if I do

```
  validates :body, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 30000, :message => ' is a bit long...'}
  validates :body, :length => {:minimum => 10, :message => ' is a bit short...'}
```

I still have a possibility of having a text which includes only `spaces` and `/r` or `/n` - non visible chars, which while the text isn't blank by definition, it is blank by looking at it

How can I validate that the text had a min and max length listed above and is also visible (not 10 spaces)

Comment: You could always try using regex to check for non-word, non-numerical, and special characters, kind of like what was suggested in this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680771/rails-custom-validation-based-on-a-regex).

Comment: Try looking at this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765020/regex-to-validate-string-having-only-characters-not-special-characters-blank) as well.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Rails adds the handy method `blank?` which checks for false, nil and empty strings as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F).
Rails also adds the handy validator `allow_blank: false`.

So in your case it should be:

`validates :body, presence: true, allow_blank: false`

---

Edit (original answer above):

As stated in the answer below, `allow_blank: false` is not needed as that's the default behaviour of `presence: true`.

Comment: Setting `allow_blank: false` is superfluous since `validates presence: true` already does what you want. 
Please note the correct answer at the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24832913/273715

Answer (score 32):

`presence: true` already does that according to 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence

> This helper validates that the specified attributes are not empty. It uses the blank? method to check if the value is either nil or a blank string, that is, a string that is either empty or consists of whitespace.

Comment: This is the same for Rails 3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#validates-presence-of

Answer (score 6):

What if you try adding something like this:

```
validates_format_of :body, :with => /\A[[:graph:]]\Z/i
```

Notes:

- `validates_format_of` lets you validate with regex
- `[[:graph:]]` lets you check a string for printable characters ([see "Character Classes"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html))