# rails validation reject if form is all whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to find a way to reject creation of a message if the form filled out is empty (including spaces and new lines). Currently I have the form set to `required: true` but that doesn't stop a user from hitting the spacebar and sending the message. I don't know if Rails has a built in validation or if there is some regex I would have to use.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482354/how-to-validate-text-isnt-blank-in-rails) can help.

Answer (score 0):

You're after a `presence` validator in your model. It will explicitly require that your field's `present?` be true, which it won't be if the column contains only whitespace.

Comment: require :attribute, presence: true

Comment: @KcUS_unico No, `validates :attribute, presence: true`.

Comment: Sorry, of course it is: validates :attribute, presence: true